# force ggplot to evaluate counter variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I ran into an interesting problem regarding how/when variables
are evaluated in ggplot constructs.

The simplest example I can think of to reproduce this is the 
following (which is supposed to place the points 1 to 10 on a plot):

```
df=data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)
panel=ggplot() + xlim(-1,11) + ylim(-1,11)
for (i in c(1:10)) {
    panel=panel+geom_point(aes(x=df$x[i],y=df$y[i]))
}
print(panel)
```

This will generate a plot with one point, i.e. the one for **i=10**
If I give **i** another value (in the range 1 to 10) and repeat the
**print(panel)** command then that particular point will be plotted.

And if I do **i <- c(1:10)** followed by **print(panel)** then all the ten points will be plotted, just as if I had issued the vectorized version:

```
ggplot(aes(x=x,y=x),data=df)+geom_point()
```

It seems to me that here **i** is only evaluated when the **print(panel)** command is issued.

I ran into this in a very complicated plot where **i** was looping through the elements of a list, and a vectorized version is not practical.

So, the question her is:
Is there a way to force ggplot to evaluate **i** for each step in the loop?

Comment: Do not use `$` within ggplot2. Use the `data` parameter ...

Answer (score 11):

The `aes()` specifically prevents evaluation. If you want evaluation, you can use the standard-evaluation version `aes_()`

```
panel=ggplot() + xlim(-1,11) + ylim(-1,11)
for (i in c(1:10)) {
    panel=panel+geom_point(aes_(x=df$x[i],y=df$y[i]))
}
print(panel)
```