# add text to ggplot in loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

In every cycle of a loop I create a `ggplot` object and I want to add text to the plot according to the cycle.

Here is my code:

```
gp <- list()

for(k in 1:3) {
 gp[[k]] <- ggplot() + 
  geom_text(aes(x = 2, y = 1, label=k), colour = "#1874CD")
 }
gp[[1]]
gp[[2]]
gp[[3]]
```

What I get is the number 3 in all plots. Why is that? And how can I manage to plot "1" in the first plot, "2" in the second and so forth?

Comment: It's because the `k` isn't evaluated until you actually print the plot. So when you run `gp[[1]]` the current value of `k` is 3, because that's the value of `k` at the end of the loop. Use `aes_` instead of `aes` to force immediate evaluation of `k`, as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39021087/496488).

Comment: Thank you very much! Did the trick!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26246791/2461552) has a nice explanation for how `aes` works.

Answer (score 3):

Try `aes_string` instead of `aes` in `geom_text`:

```
gp <- list()

for(k in 1:3) {
  gp[[k]] <- ggplot() + 
    geom_text(aes_string(x = 2, y = 1, label = k), colour = "#1874CD")
}
gp[[1]]
gp[[2]]
gp[[3]]
```